# Invalid filename given bluetooth transfer bash script

Tags: bash, shell

being the lazy bum that I am, I've been trying to make a simple bash script to transfer files from com to my phone. However, when I run the following script, i keep getting "invalid filename given"

```
for f in *.mp3
do
  bluetooth-sendto --device=<ADDRESS> ${f}
done
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction? :)

Comment: Quote `$f` -> `"$f"` to prevent it undergoing word splitting and globbing.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your files properly contains spaces. When you *don't* quote parameter expansions they will undergo word splitting and globbing. As a rule of thumb you should *always* quote:

```
for f in *.mp3; do
  [ -e "$f" ] || continue
  bluetooth-sendto --device=<ADDRESS> "$f"
done
```

The reason for `[ -e "$f" ] || continue` is that if no files is found literal `*.mp3` will be in `f`.